# orchard welcome message

Tags: orchardcms

I've got an Orchard CMS application and I want to change the welcome message that is shown by Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\Views\User.cshtml.  Specifically, I want to show the user's name as defined in my own database as opposed to the CMS stored user name.  The model for my database is defined in my own project that I've added to the Orchard solution.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override that template in your theme. Copy the file from where it is now to themes/yourtheme/views and start customizing it. As for changing where the user name comes from, you may be taking this from the wrong end. Of course, you could inject your own service using WorkContext, but it seems like you should have replaced the built-in membership classes with your own. The original template would then pick it up naturally. You can replace existing services using the SuppressDependency attribute.

Comment: Thanks - that looks good.  Not going to argue about the membership classes.  I've picked this project up a contactor with a one week handover and, having never worked on Orchard (or any other CMS), it's a steep learning curve :)